# Really weird Php Mail::factory Issue

Tags: php, email, smtp

I have this really weird  issue that am troubled with and do not know how to fix it!

Sample code i used here Wroks and sends me the email correctly!

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = "Web Master <contact@sample.com>";
$to = "bob <sample@sample.com>";
$subject = "Test email using PHP SMTP\r\n\r\n";
$body = "This is a test email message";

$host = "mail.emailsrvr.com";
$username = "sample@sample.com";
$password = "11111";

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
  'To' => $to,
  'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
?>
```

But when i put this code into a email password reminder php code it stops working!
i have put the code at the very front or at the place where u click to send button
to trigger, nothing works and i have no idea why!
the funny part is i had it working if i slowly copy in parts of the code and it WORKS
for about the first one or two email and it stops working after...

the code that comes before the reminder.php before the email script is below

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors","1");
ini_set("display_startup_errors","1");
if(get_magic_quotes_runtime())
{
    set_magic_quotes_runtime(false);
}

include("include/dbcommon.php");

$cEmailField = "email";
$reminded=false;
$strSearchBy="username";

include('libs/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty();

$strUsername="";
$strEmail="";
$strMessage="";

$conn=db_connect();
//  Before Process event
if(function_exists("BeforeProcessRemindPwd"))
    BeforeProcessRemindPwd($conn);
```

Please ! if you have any idea on the solution to this?

Comment: anyone see some mistake i did?

Comment: If it works but then stops working, it's most likely not the code but the mail transport. Contact support of the SMTP server you use and ask them how you can exclude/ensure that it is (not) a problem transferring the message.

Comment: Could there be a problem with sending the mails (as @hakre mentioned) or with the other 2 php files that you include in the second piece of code? Is there any way that one of those files crashes / times out from time to time (the library probably not but the DB stuff? )

Comment: Also, could you please explain the "if i slowly copy in parts of the code" bit? What exactly do you do and in what file ?

Comment: This is an issue with your host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mail("sample@sample.com","Test email","test body here");
```

check if this works?

Comment: Hardly bounty material...?

Comment: I still can't get this to work, but the normal function did.. I guess I will just stick to what works..